# how to create wordpress network with multiple wordpress installations

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

i want know it is possible to have 2 or 3 wordpress installations ,get together create ,and create a network .,which will share user  data across the network,
if there any reference that will be great,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a network, you don't need multiple installs.

I would just start researching networks more via the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Be sure you also read [Before you create a network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network).